# Trying to find the total number of an event

Tags: python, statistics, data-analysis

Hey guys so I'm using python for data analysis. and one of the questions I was asked is to find the total number of an event for females only in a 2D List that I have already created, I'm unsure as how to answer this question I've tried a few different ways but I cant seem to get it working. below is my 2d list and the code I've written.  Also the data should be stored in its own list.

import statistics as st

```
data = [["1987", "male", "15-24", 21],["1987", "male", "35-54", 16], ["1987", "female", "15-24", 14], ["1987", "male", "75+", 1],
       ["1987", "male", "25-34", 9], ["1987", "female", "75+", 1], ["1987", "female", "35-54", 6], ["1987", "female", "25-34", 4],
       ["1987", "male", "55-74", 1], ["1987", "female", "5-14", 0], ["1987", "female", "55-74", 0], ["1987", "male", "5-14", 0],
       ["1988", "female", "75+", 2], ["1988", "male", "15-24", 17], ["1988", "male", "75+", 1], ["1988", "male", "35-54", 14],
       ["1988", "male", "55-74", 4], ["1988", "female", "15-24", 8], ["1988", "female", "55-74", 3], ["1988", "female", "25-34", 5],
       ["1988", "male", "25-34", 5], ["1988", "female", "35-54", 4], ["1988", "female", "5-14", 0], ["1988", "male", "5-14", 0],
       ["1989", "male", "75+", 2], ["1989", "male", "15-34", 18], ["1989", "male", "35-54", 15], ["1989", "male", "55-74", 6], 
       ["1989", "male", "15-24", 12], ["1989", "female", "35-54", 7], ["1989", "female", "15-24", 5], ["1989", "female", "25-34", 2],
       ["1989", "female", "55-74", 1], ["1989", "male", "5-14", 0], ["1989", "female", "75+", 0], ["1989", "male", "5-14", 0]]


print()

total_fem_suc = []
for instance in data:
    if instance [1] == "female":
        total_fem_suc.append(int(instance[3]))
print(total_fem_suc)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following approach to avoid storing the elements in the list:

```
fem_suc_total = sum(elt[3] for elt in data if elt[1] == 'female') # 62
```

Also, you could use the list comprehension approach which is preferred to traditional looping in Python:

```
fem_suc = [elt[3] for elt in data if elt[1] == 'female']
fem_suc_total = sum(fem_suc)
```